# Possible to show part of page in Bootstrap Dialog js plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Plugin on Github: https://github.com/nakupanda/bootstrap3-dialog

Relevant JS:

```
        $(".dialog-launch").on("click",function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            BootstrapDialog.show({
                title: 'Basic Title',
                message: $('<div></div>').load('some-page.php'),
                buttons: [{
                    label: 'Cancel',
                    cssClass: "btn-danger",
                    action: function(dialogItself){
                        dialogItself.close();
                    }
                }, {
                    label: 'Continue',
                    cssClass: 'btn-primary',
                    action: function(){
                        // Continue Function;
                    }
                }]
            });
        });
```

What this js does is opens a Bootstrap Dialog with the contents of some-page.php.

What I would like to do is load only part of the some-page.php like so:

```
<!-- LOAD THIS -->
<div class="first-section-to-load">...</div>
<!-- END FIRST LOAD -->

<!-- LOAD SECOND -->
<div class="second-section-to-load">...</div>
<! END SECOND SECTION -->
```

The reasoning is because I need a modal that has a form in multiple parts. It loads Step 1 on launch and once the user presses the Continue button it will then remove Step 1 and load Step 2 in it's place.

So far it seems easy enough to manipulate the data in the modal via button action and even changing the message where it's loading some-page.php. I could easily put each step in a separate file and just alter the message and change out the pages it's loading but that seems less efficient then if I could just put all the form content I want in the some-page.php and then use the buttons to manipulate what is shown to the user and when.

Is this possible? I have loaded up a fiddle for experiments: http://jsfiddle.net/qyamk5m4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
    $(".dialog-launch").on("click",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        BootstrapDialog.show({
            title: 'Basic Title',
            message: $('<div></div>').load('some-page.php #section-one-id'),
            buttons: [{
                label: 'Cancel',
                cssClass: "btn-danger",
                action: function(dialogItself){
                    dialogItself.close();
                }
            }, {
                label: 'Continue',
                cssClass: 'btn-primary',
                action: function(dialog){
                    dialog.setMessage($('<div></div>').load('some-page.php #section-two-id'))
                }
            }]
        });
    });
```